# #define error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c-preprocessor

Do you know why I'm getting these errors out of this piece of code?

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({\
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);\
    (type *)( (void *) ( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) ) );})
```

> error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '(' token
>   error: '__mptr' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Could it be that __mptr hasn't been declared anywhere?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio (or any non-GCC-ish compiler)?

Comment: Why do you need the parantheses? They seem to be the problem.

Comment: There's not quite enough information in this post. Are you getting the error when you *use* the macro, or are you you getting the error  on the lines *defining* the macro?  Can you give some short excerpts of the code lines that the compiler errors point to?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the help!

Replacing 'typeof' by a typeof with two underscores on each side solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

"typeof" is GCC extension https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html

To use it one needs to specify GCC standard by using -std=gnu11 compiler option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can replace the macro with this:

`#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
  ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - (unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))`

I guess the way parantheses are used in your macro is the reason for the issue.